# Get rid of empty class implementing AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Following the reference post about Spring Security for a web (MVC) application [[1](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/)], I see myself having to implement such a class:

```
package com.my.web.config;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class MySecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

Wouldn't it be easier to just have some annotation to do the work? Like all the @EnableXXX we already have?

Or override a registering method in the web app initializer, like I have:

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { MyWebAppConfig.class, MyDataConfig.class, MyWebSecurityConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { new CharacterEncodingFilter(CharEncoding.UTF_8) };
    }

}
```